# Arch Linux on X1 Carbon (Gen7) - mouse click loses hold when selecting text

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, mouse, wayland

I have an X1 Carbon (Gen) running 5.7.12-arch1-1 kernel with Wayland/Gnome.  When I click to select text in any application, the mouse tends to lose the depressed click before I have finished selecting the text.  When I move the mouse more slowly, the select process is more reliable. It is like the input from the mouse is not being consistently registered or that the act of clicking and holding the mouse is somehow being forgotten.

The problem seems to vary in severity.  This problem did not exist when I first installed Arch but I am unable to diagnose what installation/upgrade caused the change. I have a Logitech USB mouse plugged directly into the laptop usb port.

I am at a loss to figure out how to debug this problem.  I have only recently switched from Ubuntu to Arch so even knowing what logs to look at is challenging.  Any pointers, suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse, or the built in one on your laptop?

Comment: Yes, the problem does not seem to be in the peripheral.

Comment: Ok, it probably isn't the mouse driver then, as I think typically the built-in trackpad would use a different kernel module. I use Arch myself, but with X. I haven't used Wayland. So, it could be an issue with Wayland? Perhaps try installing the X version of Gnome or LXDE, to see if it works ok with X?

Comment: I switched to the X version of Gnome and things seemed better at first but I find it still happens.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you try different things to use the process of elimination to pinpoint where the issue is. If you have tried different mouse devices and both X and Wayland give the problem, then I'm not sure what else it could be. I would probably try making a bootable USB for another distro (Ubuntu, Mint) and see if you get the same issue with that. It seems very bizarre.

Comment: It seems to have been the mouse hardware after all.  Faulty initial testing on my part.  Thanks @Time4Tea!